# Python: A good regular expression for text parsing in this example

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

There are words with their pronunciation. anyway i am interested in extracting just the first word

```
A  AH0
A'S  EY1 Z
A(2)  EY1
A.  EY1
A.'S  EY1 Z
A.S  EY1 Z
A42128  EY1 F AO1 R T UW1 W AH1 N T UW1 EY1 T
AAA  T R IH2 P AH0 L EY1
AABERG  AA1 B ER0 G
AACHEN  AA1 K AH0 N
AAKER  AA1 K ER0
AALSETH  AA1 L S EH0 TH
AAMODT  AA1 M AH0 T
AANCOR  AA1 N K AO2 R
AARDEMA  AA0 R D EH1 M AH0
```

I tried `regex= r"(\A[A-Z]+\b) | (\A[A-Z\'w]+\b)"`

\A : Matches only at the start of the string.

```
I still dont get the regex.
I have few conditions:
1. No starting whitespace - can be \s
2. (\A[A-Z\'w]+\b) in this:
```

\b : again from http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html I thought this is acting like a boundary b/w alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric.

```
What is happening is these are being collected:
('A', ' ')
('A', ' ', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'R') is actually AABERG
('A', ' ', 'C', 'E', 'H', 'N') AACHEN
('A', ' ', 'C', 'O', 'N', 'R')
('A', ' ', 'D', 'M', 'O', 'T')
('A', ' ', 'E', 'D', 'M', 'R')
('A', ' ', 'E', 'H', 'L', 'S', 'T')  
('A', ' ', 'K', 'R', 'E') AAKER
```

I am collecting them as a list of tuples (one word as individual letters in a tuple)
Now thats what i am doing. The problem is I see that when the repeating letter A repeats more than once here: 'A' is not being included instead a 
' ' empty blank gets added. what is happening? I want to extract only the first starting word here, `not A(2) or whitespaces or (,),[,] or any other symbolic character except for "'\'"` thats why i thought of adding [A-Z\'w]

Also if anyone can tell me how to add multiple conditions, lets say

`regex= r"(\A[A-Z]+\b) | (\A[A-Z\'w]+\b) | ^\A[A-Z]+\b"` does this work ^\A[A-Z]+\b" in extracting or ^\A[A-Z]+\s" this is better? I am confused.

## Update

If I also want something like

```
;Semi-colon
A.S
.Dot
```

is `r'[^\SA-Z\\]+` going to work? That `'\\'` is taken from Inbar Rose's solution below. Still figuring out what that does

Comment: You question is very confusing. You need to relax, calm down, and edit your question to include the following: A brief explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, The code you have so far, Some sample Input, the output you are getting / or any error you are getting. And finally, the expected output - what you want the code to do to your sample data.

Comment: @InbarRose ok ill add it right now. There aren't any errors. this is semantically not correct though. You see I start off the thread with " i am interested in extracting just the first word" from the list given below. thats exactly what i would like to accomplish

Comment: @user2290820: Part of the issue is that you need to define __the first word__. Is `A.S` a word? Or would only `A` be the first word in that string?

Comment: @sharth True True. Added the Update in the Question just for that. see above.

Comment: @user2290820: I would argue that you __did not__ answer my question. If you look at my answer, I've given exactly what the output is from the execution of my code. What I'd like to see from you, is for a given input (perhaps the one you've shown, perhaps one that is more complicated), what you would like the output to be.

Comment: @sharth Irrelevant. your solution I +1ed suffices. Do you need to look at my whole you mean to say? and its output as well. i doubt that will be of use.

Comment: @user2290820: If you're happy, then don't mind the followup question. The purpose was to further understand your original question, but it looks like you're happy with the answers that have been given.

Comment: @sharth Yes its more of pondering over regex. something that needs to be learnt.then only i can apply it to different expressions for various purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% on what you expect the output to be, but here's a shot at it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

pattern = r"^([A-Za-z]+)"

text = """A  AH0
A'S  EY1 Z
A(2)  EY1
A.  EY1
A.'S  EY1 Z
A.S  EY1 Z
A42128  EY1 F AO1 R T UW1 W AH1 N T UW1 EY1 T
AAA  T R IH2 P AH0 L EY1
AABERG  AA1 B ER0 G
AACHEN  AA1 K AH0 N
AAKER  AA1 K ER0
AALSETH  AA1 L S EH0 TH
AAMODT  AA1 M AH0 T
AANCOR  AA1 N K AO2 R
AARDEMA  AA0 R D EH1 M AH0"""

def main():
    print re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output from this is:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'AAA', 'AABERG', 'AACHEN', 'AAKER', 'AALSETH', 'AAMODT', 'AANCOR', 'AARDEMA']
```

---

We could make some small changes to this answer if your problem became more complicated. Let's say you needed different line delimiters than just `\n`. The following pattern will not use `MULTILINE` but will produce the same output as before. In the first set you could add additional characters that you could match against, such as a `;`.

```
pattern = r"[\n^]([A-Za-z]+)"
print re.findall(pattern, text)
```

Comment: not sure why -1 ... so +1 to offset it as this should work fine ... but I still dont understand why you would want to use a regex for this

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Sure. I'll agree that a regex is likely overkill for this problem. But it's always possible that this is the beginning of a much harder problem that they would be appropriate for.

Comment: @sharth yes normally i wouldnt like to add a chapter of a submodule as to what is being processed and waste time here to go thru all the code. one more thing, if I want something like 'A.S' above or .dot? then?

Comment: @sharth So I can add multiple conditions for one string pattern like [\n^]([A-Za-z]+) : What I get is: search for newline and start of a char which is ^ hence \n^, is how i understand. is that correct? why in a square bracket? and ([A-Za-z]+) is sure to not include anyu whitespace or addition non alphanumeric characters right?

Comment: The square brackets in the case of `[\n^]` means that either `\n` or `^` will be matched, and only one of them. Likewise `[A-Za-z]` means that only capital and lowercase letters will be matched, and only one character. The [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) talks about this relatively clearly.

Comment: @sharth so [] is what i am looking for. Thanks. never knew that. Yea ill try this out right now

Answer (score 5):

If what you want is simply the first word on each line of a text you don't even need regular expressions:

```
for line in text.split('\n'):
    first_word = line.split()[0]
```

But if you insist on using regular expressions (this will also make sure you only grab Alphabetica (`A-Z`) and `\`):

```
for line in text.split('\n'):
    first_word = re.match(r'([A-Z\\]+)', line, re.I).group(1)
```

Note, this assumes `text` is a string with line breaks (new lines) if you are in fact reading from a file, or other source, the iteration will be different.

Comment: great minds think alike or something like that ... although I dont see any reason at all to use a regex for this problem (+1 all the same :) )

Comment: @JoranBeasley The OP did mention he did not want any non alphabet characters except '\'

Comment: @JoranBeasley regex is needed because i am not just splitting by \n, there may be ;Semi-Colon0 seh mi ...something that kind of a line starting off with a character which is not a word and its not exactly splitting my \n

Comment: @InbarRose [A-Z\\]+ what is the significance of this '\\' ?

Comment: `first_word = line.partition(' ')[0]` or `first_word = line.split(None, 1)[0]` if you wanted...

Comment: @user2290820 using only one `\` is telling the regex interpreter to escape the next character, so you need to use two of them to mean only a single `\`. Jon - the OP stated clearly that he wants to be able to grab only the alphabetic and `\` at the start of a line, partition, or split will give also numbers or characters.

Answer (score 1):

why do you need a regex for this?

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
     lines = list(f)
print [l.split()[0] for l in lines
```

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think  “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

Comment: with open(path) as f:
    lines = list(f)
    for l in lines:
        print [l.split()[0]]
        
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['##']
['!EXCLAMATION-POINT']

Comment: not exaclty what i am looking for. like i said.regex is needed.